# How to manually focus to next input field with jquery virtual keyboard?

Tags: javascript, jquery, virtual-keyboard

I am using jquery virtual keyboard in my page. i have two input boxes. On my page load i manually focus the first input field. so that virtual keyboard enabled. on pressing VK Tab in focus to next input field. so far fine. But as per new requirement when the user enters 8 characters in the first input field then the focus should move to next input field. I tried adding the condition in the virtual keyboard button click event and set     `$('#nexIPField').focus()`     but not working as expected. How to achieve this?

What i am thinking is manually trigger the tab key event solve the problem. If it is right how to trigger the tab key event?

Answer (score 2):

One way to do this would be to associate an `onchange` event on your textbox.

Call a function on change to check the number of characters which have been typed. Once it reaches 8, trigger a focus on your next sibling.

`<input type='text' onchange='checkChars()'/>`

Javascript:

```
function checkChars() {
   //take length of that input field and check for 8
   $(this).next().focus();
}
```

Comment: change triggers only when the cursor moves out of the text box. i need that in key up(i.e) jquery virtual keyboard's key button press

Comment: `onchange` will trigger when the value of the text box changes.